# How to enter in the body of a destructor in MS VS 2010?

Tags: c++-cli, visual-studio-debugging

When I try to debug a C++/CLI program in MS VS 2010 and use key `F11` to enter the body of a destructor of some class the debugger skips this step.

How to force the debugger to enter the body of a destructor?

Comment: Debug or release build? In release builds, it may be optimized out.

Comment: @MSalters  It is a debug build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another [leaky abstraction issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29607240/17034), you can tell what's going on when you look in the Output window after you tried to step:

> Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'Foo.Dispose'

Luckily the debugger still allows you to set a breakpoint on the destructor.  Which is the workaround.